# Используемая версия языка в Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Как узнать, какая версия языка C# используется в Visual Studio 2015? Как обновить до последней?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: @АртемНиколаевич там сказано как сменить версию фреймворка.  Он и так стоит последний, но некоторые синтаксические конструкции стали недоступны когда открыл проект не в 2017 а в 2015

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156603/c-sharp-7-0-in-visual-studio-enterprise-2015

Comment: @АртемНиколаевич А есть способ обойтись без Nuget-a?

Comment: второй ответ по ссылке?

Comment: To be able to use the new C# 7 language features, you need a C# compiler that understands these features.
VS.NET 2017 has a compiler that supports these features. The C# compiler incorporated in VS.NET 2015 does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не первый подобный вопрос, поэтому стоит написать подробно.

VisualStudio - это IDE, т.е. всего лишь средство интеграции различных компонент в единую среду для удобной разработки.

Поддержку конкретной версии языка осуществляет компилятор, который в ходит в состав дистрибутива .NET Framework, и **только используется** студией. Аналогично и MSBuid, для сборки проектов. Фактически это означает, что вы можете писать код в блокноте и собирать ваши проекты без студии, только это неудобно.

Правда остается одна проблема, из-за которой приходится обновлять студию для поддержки новых языковых конструкций - это подсветка синтаксиса и синтаксический анализатор, который показывает ошибки в коде до компиляции. Эти компоненты являются частью студии, и, естественно, ничего не знают о нововведениях в языке. Поэтому при использовании студии младшей версии, вы сможете нормально собирать проекты только этой и более младших версий, для старших версий сборку не даст выполнить предварительный синтаксический анализ, если обнаружит правильные, но незнакомые ему конструкции. Есть некоторые методы обхода этого ограничения, ссылку уже приводили в комментариях, но это не отменяет того факта, что синтаксический анализатор будет считать ошибочными незнакомые ему конструкции, просто при сборке его мнение не будет учитываться.

В конце концов, для разовых доработок приблудного проекта можно воспользоваться Community-изданием студии, если повышение версии коммерческого издания в ближайшее время не планируется.

Comment: Видимо все таки придется установить 2017.  Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Для сборки проекта под конкретный .Net Вам нужно выполнить 2 условия:

1. Установить требуемую версию .Net на компьютер (тоже потребуется и пользователю Вашей продукции)
2. В настройках проекта (обращаю Ваше внимание: не свойства solution, а ниже по иерархии) указать под что собирать.

Не знаю точно - возможно понадобится перезагрузка студии/компьютера.

Часть синтаксических конструкций Вам действительно будет не доступна - за "синтаксический сахар" отвечает к сожалению студия - поэтому по возможности ставьте последнюю VS (сейчас 2017 вроде)

Comment: конструкции будут доступны и будут компилироваться, но да - студия будет их подчеркивать красненьким