# Ошибка при использовании кортежей

Tags: c#, .net

У меня стоит vs15. Я взял код из интернета и решил в нём разобраться. Там используются кортежи. Так вот у меня почему они подчёркиваются.
Пробовал:
-Поставил .NET framewor 4.7 и 4.7.1 
-Попытался установить через NuGet

> System.ValueTuple

появляется ошибка:

> An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for
>   'System.ValueTuple' from source 'nuget.org'

В общем последнее моё решение в установке vs17. Но вдруг кто-то знает как решить проблему?

Прикрепляю начало кода, тут видно, что всё подчёркивается. А вот на работе на vs17 всё хорошо проходит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы имеете в виду Visual Studio 2015? Ну так он просто ещё не знает о C#7, вот и подчёркивает.

Comment: Связанный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/735048/198316

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Tuple<double[], double[]>[] _trainset = new Tuple<double[], double[]>[]
{
  new Tuple<double[], double[]>(new double[] { 0, 0 }, new double[] { 0, 1 })
};
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.
А не знаете почему код на картинке в vs17 работал?

Comment: @alladuh Пожалуйста. Хм, мне неясно, почему Вы ожидали, что он будет компилироваться. Там явно недостаточно информации, чтобы компилятор понял, что декларируется и создается.

Comment: @Igor, вроде достаточно

Comment: @Grundy Это седьмой C#, что ли? Или уже восьмой?

Comment: @Igor, вроде седьмой

Comment: @Igor  это седьмой.